# How to eliminate WAR foldername from Tomcat URL?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

Lets say i have a war called `mywar.war` and its deployed in apache tomcat. Upon startup its exploded into a directory called `mywar` inside `webapps` folder of tomcat.
This effectively means that i need to use `mywar` inside the URL like `http:\\localhost:8080\mywar\xxx`.

Is there any way so that i could directly access like this `http:\\localhost:8080\xxx` by still keeping the exploded `mywar` folder inside `webapps`.

Please note that i don't have any UI access to tomcat so whatever setting i need to do to achieve above has to be via configuration itself.

Is their any URL rewrite kinda thing in tomcat?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Name it `ROOT.war`

Comment: @f_puras : is this the only option? I cant renaming every war to root.war. there must be some other solution to keep the exploded folder and still do what i want to achieve. No url rewrite possible?

Comment: AFAIK Tomcat has no capabilities for URL rewriting. But it might be a good idea to have it running behind an ordinary web server, which is the best choice for URL manipulations anyway.

Comment: @f_puras : tomcat9 has rewrite url valve.  You might want to have a look